# h:outputLink points to http://localhost:8080/Org/faces/gone4.com/faces/index.xhtml instead of gone4.com

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, hyperlink

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5. In my treeTable, I am using `<h:outputLink>` as below.

```
<p:column styleClass="names">
    <h:outputLink value="#{nodeData.name}"
                  rendered="#{nodeData.id ne 0 or not empty nodeData.id}"
                  target="_blank">

                  #{nodeData.name}
    </h:outputLink>
<p:column>
```

Where `nodeData.name` is my URL, but when I click on it does not work but when I right click and say open link in new tab it redirects to this location:

XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: `http://localhost:8080/Org/faces/gone4.com/faces/index.xhtml`
Line Number 1, Column 1:

But my URL is gone4.com.

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: The error message indicates something which is unlikely to be related to `<h:outputLink>` only. Your XHTML file itself appears to be corrupted. It may contain invalid/incorrect XHTML elements (or no elements at all - the basic structure of the XHTML file may be invalid).

Comment: If I don't click on the link it's working fine However when I click on the link then it redirects to link which is not correct. In above case the link is gone4.com

Comment: Look into the URL in the generated HTML code and see if it is what you are expecting it to be from `value="#{nodeData.name}"`.

Comment: In the generated HTML code it shows <a target="_blank" href="gone4.com/">gone4.com/</a>

Comment: If `"#{nodeData.name}"` returns `gone4.com` as it appears from the comments, this is not what you want the `value` attribute to provide with. Provide the `value` attribute of `<h:outputLink>` a URL of your interest instead where you want to redirect to, when that link is clicked.

Comment: I have tries adding http:// before "#{nodeData.name}" in value, when i click on it, It does work, But if I right click and say open link in new tab Its working.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to an external website through an `<h:outputLink>`? In that case, it would require a full-worthy URL of that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gone4.com` is not a valid absolute URL. It resembles a domain name which could be interpreted as a relative URL. Any relative URL linked in the HTML document is interpreted relative to the HTML document's base URL which defaults to the current request URL (as you see in browser's address bar).

You need to make it a valid absolute URL. Basically, the link should look like this:

```
<a href="http://gone4.com">
```

and thus **not** this

```
<a href="gone4.com">
```

Fix your model accordingly that it holds the right URLs. Else, manually prefix `http://` in front of those domain names.